# Mysql six table join code doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Current MySQL Query:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM std_results_lev1_sem1 A JOIN std_results_lev1_sem2 B
     ON A.std_id = B.std_id
     JOIN std_results_lev2_sem1 C
     ON B.std_id = C.std_id
     JOIN std_results_lev2_sem2 D
     ON C.std_id =D.std_id
     JOIN  std_results_lev3_sem1 E 
     ON D.std_id = E.std_id
   JOIN  std_results_lev3_sem2 F 
     ON E.std_id = F.std_id
ORDER BY std_id ASC;
```

All of these tables have same `std_id` column

Comment: Showing a data structure would be great. And also, are you getting any error or you are not getting desired result?

Comment: What is the error, and the error log

Comment: no error displays & also no out put displays

Comment: all table have same columns.{std_id ,
 course_code ,
 accademaic_year ,
 course_type ,
 marks ,
 grade ,
 status }

Comment: @Andrew almost never use `NATURAL JOIN` in production code. You never know when the schema might change.

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set..but all table have some values...

Comment: Oh, I wonder if you want is a UNION instead of a JOIN. It doesn't sound like the type of data you would join. Plus, what's the point of joining them if you're only `SELECTing` from table A?

Comment: @Andrew an `INNER JOIN` is the semantic equivalent of `WHERE EXISTS` if at most one joined row exists (or `SELECT UNIQUE` is used).

Comment: actually I'm trying to display all these table data in my web page...that's why try to get all data...

Answer (score 2):

the std_id in order by is ambiguous.

```
ORDER BY A.std_id ASC;
```